# How can I pass random prop from api to another component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a movie API, and I have a hero and poster component. From the Hero I pass movie array to the Poster component, where I should  display any random recent movie. It should be the new one every time user refreshes the page. But for now I pass the whole array of movies and it display all of them.
Hero component:

```
const Hero = ({movies}: MovieProps) => {
  return (
    <div className="hero">
        {movies.filter((movie) =>(       // here i pass movie props to the poster
          <Poster movie={movie} key={movie.title}/>
      ))}
        <Container movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Poster component:

```
const Poster = ({ movie }: { movie: MovieType }) => {
  return (
    <div className="poster">
        <div className="desc">
            <span className="title">{movie.title}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="image">

        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For now poster component is just the movie title, but basically, it display all the movies through `map()`, and I want to pass just one random movie. I thought I can do it somehow through `Array.filter()`, but I'm not sure how exactly.

MovieType and MovieProps types:

```
export type MovieType = {
        vote_average: string,
        title: string,
        tagline: string,
        date: string,
        poster_path: string,
    };

export interface MovieProps {
     movies: MovieType[],
      };
```

Update:
So I created useState to change the movie object like this:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<MovieType>();
```

And I also created useEffect:

```
useEffect(() =>{
    setMovie(movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)]);
    console.log(movie);
  },[])
```

But now I have the next error when passing props to the Poster component:

```
    <Poster movie={movie} key={movie.title}/> //here I have an error: Type 'MovieType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MovieType'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass one movie down into the component by having a function which selects at random one of the array elements. This can be done using this line of code.

```
const movie: MovieType = movies[Math.floor(Math.random() * movies.length)];
```

This will randomly select a movie from the array, which can then be stored in the component's state and thus passed down into a child component.

If you call this when the component initializes, the movie will be selected and remain constant until the component is dropped.

Comment: i tried it but i have en error: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "title", movie is undefined`, is it because i didn't definy types from typescript?

Comment: Yes you will need to include the type in the variable definition (now reflected in answer) and pass the prop down with type MovieType.